# Fnd specific place in string and get data from it

Tags: php, regex, string, strpos

I have string with multiple image tags in it.
Like this

```
<img src="/files/028ou2p5g/blogs/9d66329f4/5844644f69fe7-64.jpg">
```

I want to find **FIRST** such tag, and get image name from it
**5844644f69fe7-64.jpg**
How can be this done in PHP asuming there is a lot of other text and tags in string ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 
Not clearly answered. Answer is not working fully. Please close it I've opened other with simplier question.

Answer (score 4):

You should use like what @moopet suggested. This is the code, but please give credit to @moopet.

```
$str = '<img src="/files/028ou2p5g/blogs/9d66329f4/5844644f69fe7-64.jpg">';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);

$first_img = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
var_dump( basename($first_img->getAttribute('src')) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex for this. Use PHP's DOM parser or an alternative to extract the tags, then use PHP's [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function on the `src` element to extract the filename.

Comment: Not that this doesn't work, but using regexes is fine for subsets of HTML, like this is.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to find all occurences and then get the first one.

Example:

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/<\s*img[^<>]+?src\s*=\s*[\'\"][^<>\'\"]+?\/([^<>\'\"\/]\.jpg)/', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); 
var_dump($matches[0]); 
?>
```